# Valores randômicos com JQuery não funcionam

Tags: jquery

Tenho este código com `JQuery`, ele faz o seguinte: Com o `loop` enquanto for `< 5` ele adiciona 5 *li's* no meu `html`, e depois ele gera um `size` randômico e adiciona no `CSS`, mas não funciona, todas minhas *li's* ficam com o mesmo valor. No `console.log(size)`, os valores são gerados corretamente, mas quando coloco no `css` ele é fixo.

```
$(function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        const bg = $('.bg-animation');

        bg.append('<li></li>')

        const li = $('.bg-animation li')

        const random = function (min, max) {
            return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
        };

        const size = Math.floor(random(200, 400));

        li.css({
            'width': size + 'px',
            'height': size + 'px',
            'bottom': '-' + size + 'px',
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação do jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/css/), o método `css` altera o estilo de **TODOS** os elementos que fizerem match ao seletor.

> Get the value of a computed style property for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more CSS properties for every matched element.

Como `$('.bg-animation li')` seleciona **todos** os `li` em `.bg-animation`, a cada iteração TODOS os `li` são alterados e passam a ter o mesmos estilos.

Para resolver esse problema vc pode adicionar o `:last` ao seu seletor, para pegar somente o último `li`: `$('.bg-animation li:last')`.

```js
$(function () {
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const bg = $('.bg-animation');

    bg.append('<li>adicionado ' + i + '</li>')

    const li = $('.bg-animation li:last')

    const random = function (min, max) {
        return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    };

    const size = Math.floor(random(1, 50));

    li.css({
        'width': size + 'px',
        'height': size + 'px',
        'bottom': '-' + size + 'px',
    })
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="bg-animation">
  <li>início</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Show, nossa, não sabia disso, mesmo com a documentação eu não preseitei atenção, só saí copiando aoskoaks